# Function Pointer into Function pointer declaration

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to send *id_generator* function into *student_function*. *id_generator* function includes *fileopen* function. How can I declare the *id_generator* pointer ?

```
  FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*); // fileopen function prototype
  int (*id_generator)(FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*),char* FILE*,char*); // the line that I want to write

  int id_generatorx(FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*),char* fstudent,char* a){
    FILE* fp;
    int b;
    
    fp = fileopen(fstudent,"r+");
    fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]", a);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen(fstudent,"w");
    b = atoi(a);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    b++;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",b); 
    fclose(fp);
    return b;
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean `send id_generator function into student_function` ? to give the pointer to the function in argument of student_function ? `How can I declare the id_generator pointer ` : I do not understand, *id_generator* is a function, what pointer you need ?

Comment: `id_generator function includes fileopen function` that has no sense, I just see *id_generatorx* calls *fileopen* but in what this important for your problem ? Please edit your question to make it clear, currently it is not possible to understand you

Comment: also `FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*); // fileopen function prototype` : is false, you define the global variable *fileopen* whose type is a pointer to a function returning a `FILE*` and getting two `char*` as parameters. Of course same for next line with a different type

Comment: Your second line does declare a function pointer. Please edit the question to describe what you're trying to solve in detail - compiler errors? The program doesn't work as expected? You can best help by editing the code to make it a [mre].

Comment: I have solved the problem, sory for my bad english. I could not express myself clearly. The problem was about declaretion of pointer of id_generator. While I was trying to declarete it, I sent `"FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*)"` as function parameter for fileopen to pointer of id_generator function pointer. I declareted it as `FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*)` and it works. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I am not sure of your exact implementation, but it seems that because C does not specify the order of evaluation for function arguments, there is likely undefined behavior in that prototype.  ( `int (*id_generator)(FILE* (*fileopen)(char*,char*),char* , FILE*,char*);` )